# Javascript add row headers to table from an array?

Tags: javascript, datatables, header, row

I have a 2d array that populates a table. Is there a way to insert a column all the way to the left?

```
//function to create the table
function createTable(tableData) {
  var table = document.createElement('table');
  var row = {};
  var cell = {};

  tableData.forEach(function (rowData) {
    row = table.insertRow(-1);
    rowData.forEach(function (cellData) {
      cell = row.insertCell();
      cell.textContent = cellData;
      let cellVal = cellData;
      //make cells different shades of green and red for pos/neg (based on %)
      if (cellVal > 0) {
        cell.style.backgroundColor = '#00e100';
      } else if (cellVal < 0) {
        cell.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
      }
    });
  });
  document.body.appendChild(table);
}
createTable(transpose_array);
```

I dont want to add values to the table because of the color conditions, Id just like to add headers to each row on the y-axis of the table using values from an array I have.

Image is below:
[image]

Comment: Where do the column headings come from?

Comment: Just add a row to the table before the loop that adds the contents of `tableData`.

Comment: I added a row to the matrix at the top like this:
transpose_array.unshift(dates_arr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `forEach()` callback gets a second argument containing the array index, you can use this to index into the headings array, and insert that as the first cell in each row.

```
//function to create the table
function createTable(tableData, row_headings) {
  var table = document.createElement('table');
  var row = {};
  var cell = {};
  
  tableData.forEach(function(rowData, i) {
    row = table.insertRow(-1);
    cell = row.insertCell();
    cell.textContent = row_headings[i];
    rowData.forEach(function(cellData) {
      cell = row.insertCell();
      cell.textContent = cellData;
      let cellVal = cellData;
      //make cells different shades of green and red for pos/neg (based on %)
      if (cellVal > 0) {
        cell.style.backgroundColor = '#00e100';
      } else if (cellVal < 0) {
        cell.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
      }
    });
  });
  document.body.appendChild(table);
}
createTable(transpose_array, price_array);
```

Comment: This just added another row on the top of all the dates

Comment: I thought that was what you wanted.

Comment: The first row doesn't get the green or red background colors.

Comment: Oh no, sorry. I want to add a column to the left of the first  numbers

Comment: What should it contain, the array index?

Comment: It will contain an array of prices such as price_array = [ 94,94.75,95.5,96.25,97,97.75,98.5,99.25,100,100.75,101.5,102.25,103,103.75,104.5,105.25,106,106.75,107.5,108.25,109,109.75,110.5 ] - the idea is to add these values going down on the left side of the table

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219768/discussion-between-bnc-stocks-and-barmar).